# jinja 2 passing arabic to rander template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ascii, jinja2, persian

hi i am using jinja2 in google app engine for rendering template but when im passinf arabic or persian string az template variable i get this error

```
    فروشگاه {{ name }}
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

below i've tried to encode it so  that it would be jinja acceptable but the string doesn't  appear at all

```
def deccode(n):
    n = n.decode("utf-8")
    n = n.encode("ascii","ignore")
    return n
name = 'رشد'
name = deccode(name)
logo = 'roshd'
logo = deccode(logo)
ss = {'name': name, 'logo': logo}
s = template.render(ss)

  <div class=" title">
<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
فروشگاه
```

so whats the best way to pass arabic to jinja 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to pass a unicode string to the template. Assuming you are on Python 2 this means prefixing the string literal with `u`:

```
name = u'رشد'
```

Also, get rid of your custom decode function. It's not needed. Make sure to save the file as UTF-8 though and add a comment in the first line of the file indicating the encoding of the file as mentioned in @manikandan's answer and [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Answer (score 0):

Follow https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Include this line at the beginning of python file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Maybe you can also remove your custom deccode() function